# Remount filesystem with mount() without knowing the filesystem type or source device

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mount

I need to remount `/` read-only with C running on Linux. So far, I've come up with the following code:

```
mount("/dev/sda1", "/", "ext4", MS_REMOUNT | MS_RDONLY, NULL);
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do that without specifying the source device (/dev/sda1) or the file system type (ext4), like the command `mount -o remount,ro /`. Can those sections of the syscall simply be replaced with `NULL`?

Comment: Run `strace mount -o remount,ro /` on a test system and see how it calls `mount`.  It may be working out the device and filesystem type from statvfs() information, digging through /proc, etc.

Comment: `mount -o remount,ro /` looks up the filesystem information like @AndrewHenle mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getmntent()` to iterate over all the mounted filesystems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html):

> **NAME**
>
> getmntent,  setmntent, addmntent, endmntent, hasmntopt, getmntent_r -
>   get filesystem descriptor file entry
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    #include <mntent.h>
>
>    FILE *setmntent(const char *filename, const char *type);
>
>    struct mntent *getmntent(FILE *stream);
>
>    int addmntent(FILE *stream, const struct mntent *mnt);
>
>    int endmntent(FILE *streamp);
>
>    char *hasmntopt(const struct mntent *mnt, const char *opt);
>
>    /* GNU extension */
>    #include <mntent.h>
>
>    struct mntent *getmntent_r(FILE *streamp, struct mntent *mntbuf,
>                               char *buf, int buflen);
> ```

Find the filesystem mounted at `/`, and get it's device from the `struct mntent` returned.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mount man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) it seems you can just omit both file system type and source mount point:

> ...
>
> **Remounting an existing mount**
>
> An existing mount may be remounted by specifying MS_REMOUNT in
> mountflags.  This allows you to change the mountflags and data of
> an existing mount without having to unmount and remount the
> filesystem.  target should be the same value specified in the
> initial mount() call.
>
> The **source** and **filesystemtype** arguments are ignored.
>
> ...